# Plutus Pioneer Program - Lecture #1 Problem with cabal build

Tags: plutus, cabal, ubuntu

I ran into this dependencies error on Ubuntu when I try to build the English Auction, does anyone have an idea how to solve it ?

```
Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-build command
or the legacy v1-build alias as new-style projects will become the default in
the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot replicate a
working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of plutus-pioneer-program-week01)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict:
plutus-pioneer-program-week01 => base^>=4.14.1.0)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, plutus-pioneer-program-week01)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: plutus-pioneer-program-week01, base
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Encountered missing dependencies:
aeson -any,
base >=4.14.1.0 && <4.15,
playground-common -any,
plutus-contract -any,
plutus-ledger -any,
plutus-tx -any,
plutus-tx-plugin -any
```

Comment: Please, include exact steps to reproduce this problem, from which repository, which branch, which version of operating system you are using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your `cabal` version is too old.

You can make sure you have the right one if you first start a `nix-shell` at the top-level directory of the `plutus`-repository, then `cd` to the code folder of the `plutus-pioneer-program`-repository and run `cabal build` from within that `nix-shell`.

Comment: awesome, thanks :)